# Installing multiple versions of Ruby 1.9.2 using RVM

Tags: ruby, version, rvm

I am trying to setup Ruby 1.9.2-p180 on my system for project specific purposes. I already have Ruby 1.9.2-p134 and Ruby 1.8.7 with me.

Do I need to replace Ruby 1.9.2-p134 with Ruby 1.9.2-p180 or can both co exist?

I'm making use of Ubuntu 10.04 OS.

Thank you..

Comment: What did you try? RVM should be able to easily handle this - just install 1.9.2-p180 with the full version number (including the patch number)

Comment: I tried rvm install 1.9.2, then later realized I need to be specific wrt the version, rvm install 1.9.2-p180 did the trick.. . Initially, i had a problem with rvm version I had, it didn't let the rvm install command itself work. This link helped :- http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/bcf8207fdd57382?pli=1. There after, I was able to install the version I required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what RVM is for.

```
rvm install 1.9.2-p180
```

Then to use it…

```
rvm use 1.9.2-p180
```

You can also use `.rvmrc` to configure projects per-directory and set the rvm default to whichever you prefer.

To list installed Ruby versions…

```
rvm list
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info wrt .rvm to configure projects..:) didn't knw bout that..

Comment: Sure thing. It's really worth it to spend a few minutes on the RVM website just poking around looking at what it can do. Also, if you use Pow (pure coffeescript rack server by 37signals) it'll pickup your RVM settings from this file.